# Matplotlib Bar Plot taking continuous values in x-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

whenever I try to plot a bar plot using matplotlib , instead of using discrete values passed in the x-axis it instead creates a continuous distribution of those values and plots it

for ex

`plt.bar([1,2,3,4],[100,332,34,123])`

the x-axis for this would be a continuous distribution instead of discrete values
[Like this plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7i5nf.png)

How can I make it take discrete values instead? I have gone through the documentation and I haven't found any option for this

The only workaround I have found is to cast the values as strings

Edit: Why do I need to specify the xticks for it to work , why isn't matplotlib treating them as the discrete values they are?

Comment: Sounds like you need to change the xticks.

Comment: You could also try changing the `[1,2,3,4]` x array input to string, and then matplotlib will treat the x values as categorical data, and thus discrete.

Comment: I haven't passed  xticks or yticks . Do I need to specify them ?

Comment: That's the workaround I have found , casting them as string still I am curious why it's happening , since I haven't been able to reproduce this problem elsewhere

Comment: As Ben commented, just do `plt.xticks([1,2,3,4)`  after plotting.

Comment: Again my question is why do I need to specify the xticks, why isn't matplotlib taking it as the discrete values they are

Answer (score 0):

Just specify the tick labels. The code below

```py
x = [1,2,3,4]
plt.bar(x,[100,332,34,123], tick_label=x)
plt.show()
```

results in

[image]

You can see this [in the documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html).